# Node.js throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Tags: node.js, express

This the error:

```
{}
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.'); Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.setWriteHeadHeaders (D:\xampp\htdocs\wisaa\node_express\node_modules\morgan\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:80:19)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (D:\xampp\htdocs\wisaa\node_express\node_modules\morgan\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:39:36)
    at ServerResponse.writeHeader (_http_server.js:233:18)
    at Object.queue.drain (D:\xampp\htdocs\wisaa\node_express\routes\index.js:52:13)
    at D:\xampp\htdocs\wisaa\node_express\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:871:23
    at D:\xampp\htdocs\wisaa\node_express\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
    at D:\xampp\htdocs\wisaa\node_express\routes\index.js:43:21
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\wisaa\node_express\node_modules\email-verify\index.js:145:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200 npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start" npm ERR! node v0.12.5 npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! node_express@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the node_express@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'. npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node_express package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www npm ERR! You can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls node_express npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: npm ERR!     D:\xampp\htdocs\wisaa\node_express\npm-debug.log`
```

This is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var _ = require('underscore');
var fs = require('fs'),
    async = require('async'),
    verifier = require('email-verify');
/* GET home page. */

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var emails = req.body.emails;

    emails = emails.split(',');

    var queue = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
        task(callback);
    }, 100);
    _.each(emails, function(e, i) {
        queue.push(function(cb) {
            var done = false;
            verifier.verify(e, function(err, info) {
                if (err) {
                    //console.log(err);
                    // fauile
                    emails.splice(emails.indexOf(e), 1);
                    var score = "Your email is nor valid neither exist";
                } else {
                    if (info.success) {
                        // success
                        res.json({
                            'message': emails
                        });
                    } else {
                        emails.splice(emails.indexOf(e), 1);
                    }
                }
                if (!done) {
                    done = true;
                    cb(null, true);
                    console.log('something bad happened!');
                }
            });
        });

    });
    queue.drain = function() {
        console.log(arguments);
        res.writeHeader(200, {
            'content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.send(JSON.stringify(emails));
        res.end();
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It was my first question so thanks for making it in correct way!!

Comment: You can accept the edit if it looks appropriate to you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll be calling [`res.json()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json) one or more times per request. That's not allowed because it sends the response (and headers hence error). There should be only one response per request.

When you do `_.each`, you're making a loop. In this case, you're adding a bunch of functions to a queue. When each function in that queue is processed you're calling `res.json()`. `res.json()` sends a response which is something you can only do once, not multiple times.

You can do any kind of processing of the emails that you need in this queue if you need to but don't actually send it with `res.json` until the callback is called, so in `drain`.

Comment: you mean to send the message:'emails' in drain

Comment: any one can please explain me. I am really new to node.js

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by @Matt Harrison , i am trying to add little description to it only.

It looks like,

```
res.json({
            'message':emails
            });
```

is getting called first which is responsible for sending the json response to the client, hence completing the request-response cycle.

So, after this point any attempt on `res` object is immaterial as response has already been sent.

Since you are getting following exception

```
new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
```

So, most probably, queue.drain() is called, which is setting the header. At this point you are getting the error.

Comment: res.send(JSON.stringify(emails)); so i should remove this line

Comment: you should not use `res` in drain(). As that has no point, since response has already been sent.

Comment: @Saurabh You should _only_ use `res` in drain, because that's the only place that you've 1) prepared your response and 2) can be sure is only called once.

Comment: @MattHarrison For that, he has to collect the emails and then send them in response. 

I mean, it depends on requirement, what he actually wants to do with the request. 
He can `return` as well after sending response in success case.

Comment: @GauravGupta I have remove the `res` from the drain then also i have the same error please help!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
verifier.verify(e, function(err, info) {
    if (err) {
       //Return the error itself
       return res.send(err);
       //The rest of your code here
       ...
}else{...}
```

you need to add the 'return' so that you don't reply twice. In a nutshell, Your code needs to have a `return` or an `else` so when there's an error you don't execute both code paths. That's where the error is coming from in my opinion.

Hope this helps.!